# Is it OK to re-submit my own work to the same class that I am retaking?

Tags: coursework, self-plagiarism

I'm retaking a class because I flunked the final which was worth most of our grades. The papers I'm resubmitting will be slightly edited, but mostly the same as I got good grades on them. Would this be considered plagiarism?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. We cannot really answer what your institution or whoever runs the course considers acceptable, so you have to ask them ([more on this](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3406)). As for the ethics, please take a look at the proposed duplicate questions.

Comment: @Buffy: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81655/discussion-between-wrzlprmft-and-buffy).